# is that possible to calculate the value between 2 or more textbox that are grouped?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a table that consists of 8 columns (A, B, C, etc). Column D and E are grouped by each month. Is it possible to calculate D and E value and return the value in column G?

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: Where does the data in the table come from?

Comment: I make a form so user can pick a date, make datatable and fill the report with that

Answer (score 0):

Here is needed more information about your scenario, as yes it’s possible, even before you make this DataTable. However in an unknown scenario, you can do that even after, as code below shows.
(And if I well understand what you want to do):

```
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable
    dataTable.Columns.Add("A")
    dataTable.Columns.Add("B")
    dataTable.Columns.Add("C")
    dataTable.Columns.Add("D")
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Result_OF_B_C")

    For i As Integer = 0 To 10

        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow)

        dataTable.Rows(dataTable.Rows.Count - 1).ItemArray =
            {"ColumnA" + i.ToString, i, i + i / 2, "ColumnD" + i.ToString}

    Next


    Dim newDataTable As DataTable = (From R In dataTable.Rows).Select(Function(R)
                                                                          Dim Cr As DataRow = CType(R, DataRow)
                                                                          Cr.Item("Result_OF_B_C") = CDbl(Cr.Item("B")) + CDbl(Cr.Item("C"))
                                                                          Return Cr
                                                                      End Function).CopyToDataTable


    DataGridView1.DataSource = newDataTable
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for your suggestion. But I think you little bit misunderstood. I want that scenario for my report via reportviewer not for my dgv :)

Comment: The purpose was that you have a Datatable with a third calculated column by two other columns. "DatagridView1" was only to test my code. It was something I guess you understood :(